# modalViewController presented from UISplitViewController comes up as the wrong orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` that is set at the rootView of my application. When `viewDidLoad` is called in my left view controller I do a check, then present a modal view controller using the following:

```
SiteConfiguration *config = [[SiteConfiguration alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
config.firstLoad = YES;
UINavigationController *configNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:config];
if ([Utility isIpad]) {
    configNav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    configNav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [[AppDelegate instance].splitViewController presentModalViewController:configNav animated:YES];
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:configNav animated:YES];
}
```

If the iPad is in landscape mode while the app loads, the modalView is shown with an incorrect orientation:

[image]

I can rotate the iPad to fix this, but WHY does it load up wrong?  I have `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` returning YES in my `SiteConfiguration` viewController. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful of where you choose to present your modal controller. 
I've had experience with some custom modal controllers and setting the orientation of the modal controller (and its shadows!) in

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
```

didn't always behave as expected.

Put your code (`presentModalViewController:configNav animated:YES`) in

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

instead. (Do this as well with any code that sets a subviews frame or does any manipulation of layers, e.g. the shadow layer and shadow properties).

As far as I can tell, the rotation may not be apparent to subviews of the rotated view until after

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
```

due to threading issues (one thread may start drawing your subview or modal controller's view before rotation is passed down to the subviews (and modal controllers) by the main thread). Someone with more experience with threads than myself might be able to shed more light on this.

Comment: whoops, i meant to type `viewDidAppear:`. i've edited my answer appropriately

Answer (score 0):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` doesn't actually rotate the interface, the app does that upon receiving a `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification.

Try adding a check for the device orientation in the `-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

To force an interface rotation, use the following piece of code.

```
UIDeviceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = toInterfaceOrientation;
```